# Pixi.js how do you use moveTo with an OOP object?

Tags: javascript, oop, pixi.js

I create a rectangle and a square object with an OOP method.

Next, i would to move my rectangle in an another position. I use the function moveTo.

My rectangle move but from its creation position and not from an absolute position.

What do I have to specify to move this rectangle to x=100,y=100 ?

```js
var container = new PIXI.Container();

var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(320, 480,{backgroundColor : 0x1099bb});

document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

requestAnimationFrame( animate );

var blue= 0x00c3ff
 
var red = 0xFF0040

var SHAPE={}

SHAPE.geom = function(posx,posy,width,height,color) {
 PIXI.Graphics.call(this,posx,posy,width,height,color);
 this.beginFill(color);
 this.drawRect(posx,posy,width,height)
}


SHAPE.geom.prototype = Object.create(PIXI.Graphics.prototype);
SHAPE.geom.prototype.constructor = SHAPE.geom;

var square=new SHAPE.geom(10,10,10,10,red)

var rect=new SHAPE.geom(200,400,80,30,blue)

rect.moveTo(100,100)

 container.addChild(square,rect);


 function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  renderer.render(container);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the PIXI docs for moveTo: https://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html#moveTo

It moves the DRAWING position to some coordinates, not the actual already existing object. So if you would use moveTo and after that draw with the graphics object, it should draw starting from that position. At least in theory (I have not used moveTo ever).

You should use the objects .x, .y or .position properties for setting where you want the display object to reside inside parent container. So something like:
rect.x = 100;
rect.y = 100;
or
rect.position = new PIXI.Point(100, 100);

If there are any issues, please let me know and I will make a plunkr for you to give you a working example. I do not have the time for that now unfortunately.

Also in general it is a good idea to make simple examples like this in [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/), [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or something equivalent. Then the person answering you can easily modify your code and show you a surely working example. It will be better for both.

Comment: var rect=new SHAPE.geom(0,0,80,30,blue) rect.position.set(100,100)

Comment: I noticed the post on html5 game dev forums :). It's probably the best place to ask for help regarding PIXI, stackoverflow isn't that active. The set-method was a new thing for me too. I suspect they are basically the same all of them: Using x and y, setting position with new PIXI.Point and that set-method.